# sed command reading external file and replace another file in a single sed line

Tags: shell, sed

I am using sed command to read an external file and replace my current file using regex as follows

```
sed -i '/<\/myxmltag>/{ 
     r readingExternal.xml
     a \</myxmltag>
     d 
}' output.xml
```

What I am looking for is to make above command in a single line like: sed ... output.xml, does anybody know how to make it work?

Comment: Note that you can also use `;`s to separate individual sed commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed. Split your script in multiple parts.

```
sed -i -e '/<\/myxmltag>/{' -e 'r readingExternal.xml' -e 'a </myxmltag>' -e 'd}' output.xml
```